Flutter deep linking across both iOS and web
I'm using go_router (GoRouter) with Flutter and trying to get both web routes and deep link routes on iOS to work, while hosting my web app at a custom base-href.  The routing seems to be working fine when I deploy to my web server and access links at my custom base-href with the route appended.
My routes are configured as follows:
/// The route configuration.
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return const AuthPage();
      },
      routes: <RouteBase>[
        GoRoute(
          path: '/AuthPage',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return const AuthPage();
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/AuthPage/:uuid',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            String? uuid = state.pathParameters['uuid'];
            return AuthPage(uuid: uuid);
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/ReportOffEntryPage/:uuid',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            String? uuid = state.pathParameters['uuid'];
            return ReportOffEntryPage(uuid: uuid);
          },
        ),
    ),
  ],
);

If for example my web server is at https://myserver, and my base-href is set to /subPath1/subPath2/myApp/, I can open my app in my browser at https://myServer/subPath1/subPath2/myApp/ReportOffEntryPage, of https://myServer/subPath1/subPath2/myApp/AuthPage, or https://myServer/subPath1/subPath2/myApp/ and the route is handled correctly.
However when deployed on iOS and I click on a link in an e-mail to https://myServer/subPath1/subPath2/myApp/ReportOffEntryPage, it opens my app, but GoRouter shows an error "GoException: no routes for location: https://myServer/subPath1/subPath2/myApp/ReportOffEntryPage/" (the whole URL from the e-mail).  I would've expected it just use the route of /ReportOffEntryPage.
My AASA file is defined as
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appIDs": [
          "teamID.appID"
        ],
        "paths": [
          "/subPath1/subPath2/myApp/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

Am I missing something that will allow both iOS deep linking and custom base-href web linking to work at the same time?
